# Need clarification on how Ember {{input}} works when getting a value

Tags: ember.js

I have the following form and controller:

```
<form {{action loadList on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=subreddit id="subreddit" placeholder="Subreddit" required="true"}}
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend( {

    subredditHeader: "aww",

    loadList: function() {

        var value = this.get('subreddit');

        if (value) {

            this.set('subredditHeader', value);         
            this.set( 'model',  App.RedditLink.findAll( value ) );

            // Clear out the input field
            this.set('subreddit', '');

        }
    }
});
```

Basically, on submit, it calls *loadList()* which uses *this.get()* to grab the value of the input field and then call a static method in my model to pull back data. This works fine right now.

Seems that *value=subreddit* is analogous to *valueBindings="subreddit"* (tell me if I'm wrong).

The question I have is why I couldn't just do this:

```
{{input value="" name="subreddit" id="subreddit" placeholder="Subreddit" required="true"}}
```

where the *value* attribute is empty.

When I tried it, *var value = this.get('subreddit');* wouldn't return the value I entered into the field. In fact, the debugger said it was undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember binds value to subreddit in the previous one. If you leave value empty it is not bound and you get undefined since there is nothing in the controller named subreddit. Try this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend( {
  myInputValue: '';
  loadList: function() {
    var value = this.get('myInputValue');
    // Other things
  }
})
```

And in template:

```
{{input value=myInputValue name="subreddit" id="subreddit" placeholder="Subreddit" required="true"}}
```

This works but it is generally better to bind value to a model's attribute.